# How to autoflush a linux "echo -n"

Tags: linux, perl, command

Given the following bash script:

testing.sh:

```
for i in {1..50}; 
do 
    sleep 0.1;
    echo -n $i;
done
```

How can I make PERL output in real time with each echo? It works fine if its `echo` but `echo -n` seems to make PERL think its one big echo, instead of separate echos.

PERL code that works with normal echo's

```
$| = 1;

open CMD, "testing.sh 2>&1 |";
         while (<CMD>) {
                print "$_ \r";
        }
close CMD;
```

If you run it you'll see that PERL won't print anything for 5 seconds (50 * 0.1s). If you simply change the `echo -n` to `echo` then it will output in real time.

The idea here is that I use the command `echo -ne "...\r"` in bash and I wish to achieve the same effect using PERL.

---

edit:

My 1..50 example was just to demonstrate. The actually thing I am looking to print in PERL in a bash progress bar that will update like:

```
[####..............................................] 6.20%
[####..............................................] 6.40%
[#####.............................................] 7.40%
```

except the bash will use \r instead of \n. This is acts similar to wget's progress bar. I am hoping to have the same effect in PERL. The good thing is that I see read can read by X chars, and the echo will be a set length. I cannot find any good examples that would fit what I am trying to do thoguh.

---

edit 2:

I got what I need read...

Now I am working on perfecting it with the progress bar. The progress bar is exactly 60 bytes, and I using the following:

```
$| = 1;

open CMD, "testing.sh 2>&1 |";

my ($buf, $data, $n);


while (($n = read CMD, $data, 60) != 0) {
  print $data;
}

close CMD;
```

Comment: Problem is, it's not Perl doing the echo, it's the shell - Perl can't control the shell's flushing behavior. doing `while (<CMD>)` tries to read a line, and Perl won't "see" a line until the shell command issues a newline. You'd have to read char-by-char instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`while(<CMD>)` reads a line at a time.  `echo -n` doesn't send newlines, so there's no "line" to read until EOF is reached.  You can use `read` or `getc` instead of the implict `readline` you get with `<CMD>` to read a character at a time. There's also the `Term::ReadKey` module in CPAN, which allows non-blocking single-character reading.